# What is the Java regex corresponding to the shell pattern 'test/*'?

Tags: java, regex

I want to see if a given string matches `'test/*'`, where the asterisk is marking any characters. How can I implement this with Java regular expressions? I tried `mystring.matches("test[/].*+")`, but it did not work.

```
test - my String
[/]  - 1× forward slash
.    - any character
*+   - 0 or more times
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: Remove the last + and try it. .* means 0 or more times. + means 1 or more times. Not sure what .*+ computes as.

Comment: @arunkumar - It should throw an error.

Comment: works nice for me!?! What exactly is not working?

Comment: @Justin, no, it should not throw an error. See: http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html

Comment: @Bart - My mistake! I wasn't familiar with possessive-quantifier syntax. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using too much syntax. Try:

```
mystring.matches("test/.*")
```

The `/` doesn't need to be in square brackets (although it would work the same anyway), and `*` means "repeat the previous thing zero or more times". Your extra `+` on the end is likely causing your problem.

Comment: works, thank you. http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html states 'X*+' matches X zero or more times. any idea what's with that?

Comment: On right, that `*+` syntax is a rarely-used "possessive quantifier" in Java. I'm not certain why it didn't work for you, I don't think I've ever used that syntax myself. In your case, regular `*` should do just fine.

Comment: @Pedro, both `matches("test[/].*+")` and `matches("test[/].*")` should produce the same (with or without the square brackets). Can you show input that the first does not match but the 2nd does?

Comment: @Pedro: Please reference the [current Java Pattern class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), not an ancient release aeons out of date.

Answer (score 2):

I think regex makes people forget that there are simpler methods out there. Unless I am just missing something can't you just use startsWith("test//") ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to put the "/" in char selection. This will make your expression more complex than necessary and will become more expensive when evaluated. Keep them as simple as possible.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String myString = "test/XYZ";
    boolean matches = myString.matches("test/.*");
    System.out.println(matches);
}
```

If you want to match only one char, don't use the star operator.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String myString = "test/X";
    boolean matches = myString.matches("test/.");
    System.out.println(matches);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

It depends what you mean by "any character".

- If you just want one single character exactly, but don't care what it is, you want `.`
- If you want "one-or-none", you want `.?`
- If you want "one-or-more", you want `.+`
- If you want "zero-or-more", you want `.*`

Also, you don't need to escape the `/` at all. So `"test/."` would match "test followed by slash followed by exactly one character".

Comment: This is wrong! `.*+` means as many **non-linebreak characters as possible, but there the `+` makes it a possessive match so th**at they were is no backtracking into that for a variant number of repetitions. `.` is a non-linebreak, `*` means as many as possible (0 or more preferring more), and `*+` makes the maximal match into a non-backtracking group, just as `(?>.*)` would also do.  `.*+` and `(?>.*)` are exact synonyms. Add `(?s)` or `DOTALL` to allow `.` to match Unicode linebreak characters, i.e. those with the vertical whitespace property: \cJ, \cK, \cL, \cM, \x85, \x{2028}, \x{2029}.

Comment: @Bart: It is more than just \012 and \015. It should be [any Unicode linebreak](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL). There are 7 of those that have `\p{VertSpace}`. Java has trouble with \x85 historically; for example, its `\s` is broken WRT \x85, \xA0, and \x{202F}. Check the current JDK source for the DOTALL thing to be sure.

Comment: @tchrist, yeah, I knew there were more but was a bit lazy to look them up :). Anyway, I can safely remove it since your comment covers all bases, so to speak. Next time, I'll be sure to use "linebreak characters" instead!